# Jsp ajax call using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this code snippet where I am passing data to another jsp file.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#click").click(function() {
        name = $("#name").val();
        age = $("#age").val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "pageTwo.jsp",
            data : "name=" + name + "&age=" + age,
            success : function(data) {
                $("#response").html(data);
            }
        });
    });     
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <br /><br /> 
    Age :<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
    <br /><br />
    <button id="click">Click Me</button>
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>
```

and in **pageTwo.jsp**, my code is

```
 <%
   String name = request.getParameter("name");
   String age = request.getParameter("age");
   out.println(name + age);
 %>
```

but this is not working.Is any mistake in my Jquery ?.Can any one please help me?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#click").click(function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    ...
    return false;
});
```

and of course install firebug or use chrome default developer tools (f12). open console and run the code.

Comment: Why is "return false;" necessary? It work's but I don't understand why.

Comment: "return false" to stop any default action. let say "#click" is a link, so now when you click on it will redirect you to some page (href url), now if you have "return false", it will not do browser default action.

"return false" you need to put at end of your code inside the callback. You can also use "e.preventDefault();" which you can put at top of your code inside the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        name = $("#name").val();
        age = $("#age").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pageTwo.jsp",
            data: "{'name':'" + name + "','age':'" + age + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#response").html(data.d);
            }
        });
    });
});
```