# Pass .jar to ajax execution via Jquery or AngularJS

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to pass .jar file to Jquery or AngularJS to execute some piece of server code with ajax request (simple upload code), so I can pack my .jar and use it everywhere.

I would NOT like to call .jsp or .jsf or similar (as exmplained here for example: [Jsp ajax call using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064350/jsp-ajax-call-using-jquery)).
I would really like know how to call .jar instead so my functionallity my be portable.

I would like to include my .jar as this (JQuery example):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "somepath/my-file.jar",
  data: { name: "myfile", location: "/path/files" }, 
  success: function (data) {
      $("#response").html(data);
  }
});
```

Java code could be also called with JavaScript as this example explains, but that is pretty old example:
http://mozilla-firefox-extension-dev.blogspot.hr/2004/11/calling-java-code-in-custom-jars-from.html

But I think through JQuery or AngularJS I would gain further possibilities.

What would be best and easiest way to debug that .jar when running that JQuery or AngularJS? Maybe remote debugging? Am I on the wrong path?

Comment: Anybody? Someone, help :)